# JQuery SerialScroll Implementation

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to implement the JQuery SerialScroll Plugin with JSFiddle and for whatever reason it is not functioning.

Does anyone have any idea as to why?

I think it could be some problem with the JavaScript within my JSFiddle.

I copied the jquery-serialScroll-1.2.2-min.js

Here is the SerialScroll Demo Page:  http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/serialScroll/

Here is my JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/Pe63x/

Although their Demo uses JQuery 1.3.2 Im using JQuery 1.5  Also I have nowrap body selected

Comment: looking at your jsfiddle I don't see you using the serial scroll at all -- what do you want to scroll?

Comment: @Hogan what do you mean?  I copied the exact JavaScript jquery-serialScroll-1.2.2-min.js   and at this point Im only trying to replicate the Demo

Comment: well the demo has other javascript.  It needs to hook up the plugin to this particular page.  The file is located here: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/serialScroll/js/init.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the demo working just fine with 1.5.2 in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/54au5/1/

Notes:

I'm using the manage resources to point at serialScroll and scrollTo

Comment: @Paul: You're looking at my jsFiddle, not Hogan's.  I was just inspecting the document with WebKit and grabbing the pieces of CSS and Javascript that were needed.  I uploaded the serialScroll and scrollTo plugins to entvibes to avoid leeching from the author.  You should be uploading them to your own server as well.

Comment: @entropo I checked out both JSFiddles. @Hogan added those using the Managed Resources, you simply added script tags. This guy's Demo mentioned nothing about needing 2 js files adding to the confusion

Comment: @Hogan I have 2 questions. What exactly did you paste in the JavaScript window? How do you find which URL to use in the Managed Resources?

Comment: @Paul : I went to his demo and did a view source.  Looking at the source I saw what URLs were being included.  I saw the js files that referenced serialScroll and scrollTo and added links to his download page as resources.  Then I clicked on his additional js file that contained information about how to link it to the page. (It had lots of good comments.) I looked at the JavaScript there pulled out the bits needed to make the top part of the demo work.  I put that in the onload part of the fiddle.  Clear as mud?

Comment: @Hogan yes thanks for that!  I think that your referring to the init.js which contained info about how to link to the page.

Comment: @Paul -- Yep init.js was the name of the file in the demo.

Answer (score 1):

SerialScroll was last updated over a year ago.  As a rule of thumb, don't use jQuery plugins that haven't been updated since the last major release of jQuery (e.g. jQuery 1.3.2 was the latest release when SerialScroll was last updated).

A modern slideshow plugin with similar capabilities (and more) is [Skitter](http://thiagosf.net/projects/jquery/skitter/).

Comment: so your saying that SerialScroll shouldnt function at all?  Well it looks like Skitter is a really cool SlideShow, but this is not what I need and its not the same as SerialScroll.

Comment: If you really need something provided by SerialScroll, I'm sure it will work if you use jQuery 1.3.2.

Comment: @Paul: that was an issue with setup.  This works: http://jsfiddle.net/entropo/Pad65/ (and it looks like it works fine with the latest jQuery)

Comment: @Paul - The actual setup code is in this document: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/serialScroll/js/init.js