# Howto use jQuery serialScroll / scrollTo (not working)

Tags: jquery, css

I'm going batty, trying to get the JQuery ScrollTo plugin working properly. I want to programatically scroll it to next and previous items.

Now, of course I've taken a look at [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783923/jquery-serialscroll-implementation) ([and associated fiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/54au5/1/)), but I can't seem to get it working for my scenario. I tried to set it up in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twashing/ukEfp/21/). I've tried to get the position and floats correct. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/twashing/ukEfp/21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got serialScroll working by eliminating any double loading of jquery or associated libraries ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345395/jquery-easing-breaks-jquery-on-wordpress)). I now only using requirejs for internal libs.